# TypeError in Python single inheritance with "super" attribute

Tags: python

I never expected the inheritance of Python **2.7** is so anti-human. Why the following code give me a TypeError?

```
>>> class P:
...     def __init__(self, argp):
...         self.pstr=argp
... 
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super.__init__(self,argp)
...         self.cstr=argc
... 
>>> x=C("parent","child")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'instance'
```

Then I changed to these 2, still vague errors:

```
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super().__init__(self,argp)
...         self.cstr=argc
... 
>>> x=C("parent", "child")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)


>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super(P).__init__(self,argp)
...         self.cstr=argc
... 
>>> x=C("parent", "child")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

## --------ADD--------

It still doesn't work as below.

```
>>> class P:
...     def __init__(self, argp):
...         self.pstr=argp
... 
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
...         super(C, self).__init__(arg1)
...         self.cstr=arg2
... 
>>> z=C("PPP", "CCC")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

## ---------ADD2----------

It seems all the 2 below code snippets work, what's the difference? And btw, when should I use the *new style class* or the *old style class*?

```
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super(C,self).__init__(argp)   #<------ C and self
...         self.cstr=argc
... 
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super(P,C).__init__(argp)  #<----- P and C
...         self.cstr=argc
```

Comment: `super` is a function. Call it with `super(C, self)`. It also needs the base class to be inherited from `object`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two responses possible for your question, according to the version of Python you're using.

### Python 2.x

`super` has to be called like this [(example for the doc)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

In your code, that would be:

```
>>> class P(object):    # <- super works only with new-class style
...     def __init__(self, argp):
...         self.pstr=argp
... 
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super(C, self).__init__(argp)
...         self.cstr=argc
```

You also don't have to pass `self` in argument in this case.

### Python 3.x

In Python 3.x, the `super` method has been improved: you can [use it without any parameters](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super) (both are optional now). This solution can work too, but with Python 3 and greater only:

```
>>> class C(P):
...     def __init__(self, argp, argc):
...         super().__init__(argp)
...         self.cstr=argc
```

Comment: Can't explain it better, +1.

Comment: Also you don't need any argument with python3 http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Indeed, post improved.

Comment: You forget to make `P` a new style class by writing `class P(object):` instead of `class P:`. See the doc for more info about it: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Comment: It's working now. But seems 2 options both working. Any difference? I added to my question.

Comment: It's written in the documentation at the link given in my response (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). In one case, it'll check via `isinstance(obj, type)` and in the other case, with `issubclass(type2, type)`.