# Multiple inheritance using Super(Subclass, self) in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, super

I'd like to understand if multiple inheritance is allowed in Python 2.7 from a class whose parent is not an object ?

Ref:[TypeError in Python single inheritance with "super" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063228/typeerror-in-python-single-inheritance-with-super-attribute) do provide some examples but I'd like to use super(Subclass, self) differently as below

Animal --> Mammal --> CannoFly & CannotSwim --> Dog

So Dog class inherits from CannotFly and CannotSwim classes. Each of the CannotFly and CannotSwim class inherits from Mammal which inherit from Animal classes

```
    class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animalName):
        print(animalName, 'is an animal.');


# Mammal inherits Animal
class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self, mammalName):
        print(mammalName, 'is a mammal.')
        super(Mammal,self).__init__(mammalName)


# CannotFly inherits Mammal
class CannotFly(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, mammalThatCantFly):
        print(mammalThatCantFly, "cannot fly.")
        super(CannotFly,self).__init__(mammalThatCantFly)


# CannotSwim inherits Mammal
class CannotSwim(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, mammalThatCantSwim):
        print(mammalThatCantSwim, "cannot swim.")
        super(CannotSwim,self).__init__(mammalThatCantSwim)


# Dog inherits CannotSwim and CannotFly
class Dog(CannotSwim, CannotFly):
    def __init__(self,arg):
        print("I am a barking dog")
        super(Dog, self).__init__(arg)



# Driver code
Dog1 = Dog('Bark')
```

When I run it I get the error  "TypeError: must be type, not classobj" which is because the CanotSwim() & CannotFly() classes are derived from Mammal which is not the base class but inheriting from Animal class.  If that was not the case, then the Super(Subclass, self) works perfectly.

Comment: Obligatory ["Python 2 is no longer supported and you should upgrade as soon as possible"](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) comment.

Comment: To inherit try looking for super().__init__

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `super` does not work with objects that don't inherit (directly or indirectly) from `object`.

Multiple inheritance is *allowed* with old-style classes, but may have unexpected behavior due to the Diamond Problem (see section 2.3 [here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html)).

For these reasons (and many others) it is recommended to *always* inherit  from `object` in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks @0x5453 very much for the reference , I understand the classic Diamond problem but what I'm unable to understand is was it allowed to have multiple inheritance from two classes which inherited from another class which inherited from another class /object. The reason is I can deal with the functional attribute/method overlook as in the Diamond problem but the code throws a run-time error and doesn't execute. Or simply I would be interested to understand best way to implement multiple inheritance in Python 2.7 for a common parent class , if at all it is possible.